# Rewrited URL giving 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using mode rewrite to make seo friendly urls. Please see the code below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule discover/([0-9]+)$ discover.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Code work in my local host but in the hosting server it doesn't work.

If i added with the file extension it works in the server but without the extension it doesn't work.

Ex: below works

```
RewriteRule discover-([0-9]+)\.html$ /discover.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Any pointers on how to make the 1st code it work? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this too,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^discover/([0-9]+)$ discover.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: code works. Had to add / in front of the file name Ex: /discover.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 1):

Turn off `MultiViews` option and check for existence of `.php` file before adding `.php` in a request:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule discover/([0-9]+)/?$ discover.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: @ anubhava example site/about or discover/1 all the urls. But my code works fine in localhost

Comment: Above rule assumes `.php` files and .htaccess are available in sie root

Comment: If that's the case then this rule will work as this is a working rule on my live website. Make sure your htaccess and mod_rewrite is enabled.